# plot norm curve over subplotted histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to plot multiple subplots containing histograms. Additionally, I would like to plot a curve showing the normal distribution for each subplot. While I found different answers on this forum on how to plot a normal curve over a single plot (histogram), I am struggling to achieve the same with subplots. I have tried the following:

```
from scipy import stats  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,4))

# create some normal random noisy data
data1 = 50*np.random.rand() * np.random.normal(10, 10, 100) + 20
data2=  50*np.random.rand() * np.random.normal(10, 10, 100) + 50

# plot normed histogram
ax1.hist(data1, density=True)

# find minimum and maximum of xticks,
xt = plt.xticks()[0]  
xmin, xmax = min(xt), max(xt)  
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(data1))

# lets try the normal distribution first
m1, s1 = stats.norm.fit(data1) # get mean and standard deviation  
pdf_1 = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc, m1, s1) # now get theoretical values in our interval  
ax1.plot(lnspc, pdf_1, label="Norm") # plot it

# plot second hist
ax2.hist(data2, density=True)

# find minimum and maximum of xticks
xt = plt.xticks()[0]  
xmin, xmax = min(xt), max(xt)  
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(data2))

# lets try the normal distribution first
m2, s2 = stats.norm.fit(data2) # get mean and standard deviation  
pdf_2 = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc, m2, s2) # now get theoretical values in our interval  
ax2.plot(lnspc, pdf_2, label="Norm") # plot it
plt.show()
```

Now my problem is that the normal curve is always optimal for the second plot but not the first. This is because of xmin and xmax, I however don't know how to fit these two commands invdividually in subplots. Does anyone have any experience with this? I have been trying all afternoon

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `plt.xticks()`, use `ax1.get_xticks()` and `ax2.get_xticks()`.  Maybe `ax1.get_xlim()`, as it would directly get the limits, default in the correct order. `ax1.margins(x=0)` would set the new limits again to the limits of the curve, so it doesn't "hang" in the air. [This tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `axes` instead of a tuple. Then you can set each axis individually using `sca`. See below if that's what you needed.

```
from scipy import stats  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


# fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,4)) << INSTEAD OF THIS DO:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2,figsize=(10,4))

# create some normal random noisy data
data1 = 50*np.random.rand() * np.random.normal(10, 10, 100) + 20
data2=  50*np.random.rand() * np.random.normal(10, 10, 100) + 50


plt.sca(axes[0]) #Refer to the first axis
# plot normed histogram
axes[0].hist(data1, density=True)

# find minimum and maximum of xticks,
xt = plt.xticks()[0]  
xmin, xmax = min(xt), max(xt)  
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(data1))

# lets try the normal distribution first
m1, s1 = stats.norm.fit(data1) # get mean and standard deviation  
pdf_1 = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc, m1, s1) # now get theoretical values in our interval  
axes[0].plot(lnspc, pdf_1, label="Norm") # plot it



plt.sca(axes[1]) #Refer to the second axis
# plot second hist
axes[1].hist(data2, density=True)

# find minimum and maximum of xticks
xt = plt.xticks()[0]  
xmin, xmax = min(xt), max(xt)  
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(data2))

# lets try the normal distribution first
m2, s2 = stats.norm.fit(data2) # get mean and standard deviation  
pdf_2 = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc, m2, s2) # now get theoretical values in our interval  
axes[1].plot(lnspc, pdf_2, label="Norm") # plot it
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey mgmussi, thanks a lot for your answer. When I try adding more subplots (axes[2], axes[3]), I get the error message "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous". Do you know how to add more subplots?

Comment: @Sanoj You need `axes[row_index][col_index]` when both the number of rows and number of columns are larger than 1. Please don't use `plt.xticks()`, but use `axes[...][...].get_xticks()` instead. Using `plt.sca()` to set the current ax works, but is very confusing and easily leads to mistakes.

Comment: @Sanoj you can either do what @JohanC suggested or you can refer to the axes using `axes[line, column]` I'm case you have more than one "dimensions" in your subplot

Comment: One last question: How can the y-axis be interpreted? Its too low to be the percentages and it also isn't the amount of values in that bin...

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it might be the percentage but divided by 100. It should all add to 100% if you sum up all bars.